# Installing windows service in windows server 2012

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have installed a Mail service in windows server 2012. The service seems to be running but the onstart event is not firing. I have set the logon account using a domain user. I have installed another service which seems to be working fine. The only difference between the 2 services is that d mail service has some DB activities. Can anyone help me with this ??

Comment: it seems like you don't have client on server which is needed to access the  database, or something else similar to this. Don't you use logging to log errors?

Comment: I have logs but there are no entries in log also

Comment: have you used try catch and logged errors at catch?

Comment: Ya i have added try block... But nothing seems to be caught

Comment: Have you tried to write errors to .log file instead of Windows log?

Comment: I have 2 schemas in oracle... 1 for development & 1 for testing.... The service is working fine with testing schema but its not connecting to development schema... But when i install d service in local machine it is working fine with both the schemas....

Comment: Then there may be network problem. Be sure to have access from server whcih you install your service to server you have your oracle installed. First try connection by using SqlPlus

Comment: I connected through Sql developer... Its connecting

Comment: Last thing that I can think of is your connectionString :)

Comment: Tat was the first thing i checked... Tats also fine :)... I am unable to guess whether is DB problem or service problem...

Answer (score 1):

Debugging Windows services is really hard, especially when the problem is at OnStart method. I'd strongly recommend using TopShelf: http://topshelf-project.com/

This way you can develop your service as console application which is easy to debug. I'm sure you'd be able to easily spot the problem if you can debug the method.

To install the application as a Windows service all you have to do is run

```
{Your.service.exe} install
```

For details of command line options check out: http://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview/commandline.html

Comment: I tried debugging it in my local machine and it is working fine... But in server it is not giving any exception or error...